# Sliding angularjs div with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, carousel

I want to display my json data with sliding feature. Here is the design of what i want to do. I saw carousel is for sliding images but i don't know how to achieve this one. Any help would be great.

[image: My design]

And here is sample code.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myDatas = [{
      Paramnames: "Travel Material",
      options: [{
          name: "Newspaper"
        },
        {
          name: "Magazine"
        },
        {
          name: "Book"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      Paramnames: "Safety & Security",
      options: [{
          name: "Health"
        },
        {
          name: "Private Policy"
        },
        {
          name: "Flight Disruption"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="myData in myDatas">
    <p class="m-t-xs font-bold"><strong>{{myData.Paramnames}}  </strong></p>
    <div class="col-sm-8" ng-repeat="myOptions in myData.options">
      <p class="m-t-xs font-bold">{{myOptions.name}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you open "My design" you will see the UX. If the question isn't clear let me know. Thanks.

Comment: At first glance, this looks rather good. You have correct data in your controller, and you iterate it correctly with `ng-repeat`. Where's the problem?

Comment: The problem is the way i display it in the DOM. I want to display it like sliding image(if you open "My design link" you will see the UX  how i want to display it).

Comment: @Ved i think the question is clear now

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer for my question. I thought it might help i used angular-slick directive its so cool. http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/